# Redirect to login page on "page not found" - Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I want to make so that if the user is not logged in and the page is not found (unexisting route), the user to be redirected to the login page instead to show the 404 page. If the user is logged in then the 404 page should be displayed. I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for any exception in **App\Exceptions\Handler@render**:

```
if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
    if ( \Auth::guest() ) {
        return redirect()->to('/login');
    }

    return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
}
```

Don't forget `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;` at the top of your file.

**EDIT**

You have to enable the session for all routes so you can have the user data on not found routes. In your **app/Http/Kernel.php** add the following items to the `$middleware` array:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ....

    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

Comment: Problem is that \Auth::guest() returns true even if you're logged in.

Comment: Use `\Auth::check()` instead of using `\Auth::guest()`. This may help.

Comment: @vivanov so the problem is that the session is not enabled on not found routes, so you don't have the user data there. Check my edit above on how to enable the session for all routes.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, that was exactly what I needed to figure out!

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your Exceptions/Handler.php

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException){

            return response(redirect(url('/')), 404);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);

    }
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because it's almost correct, however the redirect status code should not be 404 but one of 30X probably

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's almost there, but actually when you're logged in, it redirects to the home page instead to go to the not found page. Appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement this would be as follows;

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
  // add your routes here;
});
```

Single route;

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users
})->middleware('auth');
```