# laravel register not public

Tags: laravel, registration, public

I want to not let anyone just open application.app/register and be able to register.

Only Admins should be able to register new User.
So all i want to do is just to redirect the user to the login page.

But when i write it in the routes, it has no effect

```
Route::get('/register', 'MainController@index');
```

i am redirecting to my main Controller which is returing a the login view.
But it has no effect. Where can i change the routing of /register

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization  you can specify an authorization and when you catch an unauthorised exception you can redirect to the login page if not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

To not let a user register, override `showRegistrationForm()` and `register()` AuthController:

```
public function register()
{

}

public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return redirect('login');
}
```

Please also remove the route, that you mention in your question, as it'll just cause you problems :-)

Comment: if you mean the AuthController in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php, then i dont have this 2 methods in it. I only got a "__construct", "validator" and "create"

Comment: Yes, they don't exist, as they are inherited. If you add the above functions, the registering of users to the public should cease to work.

Answer (score 0):

Though @headan's solution also works fine. I want to show you another way to do that.
you can use following code if you want to remove register from the route and default auth form.

```
Auth::routes(['register'=>false]);
```

This will return 404 for an authorised user not redirect them to the login page.
for redirect to the login page you may change in file **Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException){

        return response(redirect(url('/')), 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);

}
```

Note: some credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42433780/1662224)